# NaN Cholesky's decomposition in Fortran if I don't use a printing subroutine

Tags: function, fortran, nan, subroutine

I programmed a function to obtain Cholesky's decomposition of a REAL matrix. The problem is that it returns NaN values in some spots of the matrix. Here is the code:

```
MODULE funciones2
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
FUNCTION cholesky(a)
USE ::comprob !Module to test whether or not a matrix is square and symmetric 
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: cholesky(:,:),u(:,:)
REAL :: a(:,:),s
INTEGER :: i,j,k,n
LOGICAL :: comp

comp=symmat(a)

IF (comp) THEN
n=size(a,1)
ALLOCATE (u(n,n))
u=0.0
u(1,1)=sqrt(a(1,1))

DO j=2,n,1
    u(1,j)=a(1,j)/u(1,1)
END DO

DO i=2,n,1
    DO k=1,i-1,1
        s=s+(u(k,i)**2)
    END DO
    u(i,i)=sqrt(a(i,i)-s)
    s=0
    DO j=i+1,n,1
        DO k=1,i-1,1
            s=s+u(k,i)*u(k,j)
        END DO
        u(i,j)=(1/u(i,i))*(a(i,j)-s)
        s=0
    END DO
END DO

cholesky=u

ELSE
    print*,"CHOLESKY: The matrix is not symmetric."
ENDIF
ENDFUNCTION
ENDMODULE
```

And the program code is:

```
PROGRAM pchol
USE :: funciones2
USE :: dispmodule
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:),af(:,:)
CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: na

na='B.txt'

a=loadm(na)
CALL DISP('A =',a,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

a=matmul(transpose(a),a)
!CALL DISP('ATA =',a,ADVANCE='DOUBLE') 

af=cholesky(a)
CALL DISP('Ach ',af,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

af=transpose(af)
CALL DISP('AchT ',af,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

ENDPROGRAM
```

"dispmodule" is a module (Jonasson, 2009) for pretty-printing matrices (you can take a look about it here: https://notendur.hi.is/jonasson/greinar/dispmodule-report.pdf ). I discovered that if I use the subroutine DISP in this part:

```
a=matmul(transpose(a),a)
CALL DISP('ATA =',a,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')
```

the problem of NaN disappears!(notice that in this last part, there is not "!" before "CALL DISP").

Why is this happening? I am going to use the Cholesky decomposition function for another function, and I can't call DISP all the time to avoid problems. How can I fix this?

Edit:
Here's the numerical result without compiling the program with the DISP subroutine:

```
A =3.00000   2.00000  4.00000   5.00000
   2.00000  -3.00000  1.00000  -2.00000
   1.00000   1.00000  2.00000   0.00000

Ach 3.74166  0.26726  4.27618  2.93987
    0.00000      NaN      NaN      NaN
    0.00000  0.00000      NaN      NaN
    0.00000  0.00000  0.00000      NaN

AchT 3.74166  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
     0.26726      NaN  0.00000  0.00000
     4.27618      NaN      NaN  0.00000
     2.93987      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Here is the numerical result when I do compile the DISP subroutine:

```
A =3.00000   2.00000  4.00000   5.00000
   2.00000  -3.00000  1.00000  -2.00000
   1.00000   1.00000  2.00000   0.00000

ATA =14.0000   1.0000  16.0000  11.0000
      1.0000  14.0000   7.0000  16.0000
     16.0000   7.0000  21.0000  18.0000
     11.0000  16.0000  18.0000  29.0000

Ach 3.74166  0.26726  4.27618   2.93987
    0.00000  3.73210  1.56940   4.07660
    0.00000  0.00000  0.50128  -1.93350
    0.00000  0.00000  0.00000   0.00648

AchT 3.74166  0.00000   0.00000  0.00000
     0.26726  3.73210   0.00000  0.00000
     4.27618  1.56940   0.50128  0.00000
     2.93987  4.07660  -1.93350  0.00648
```

EDIT 2: I assigned new variables to every new computed matrix, but the problem remains.

```
PROGRAM pchol
USE :: funciones2
USE :: dispmodule
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:),af(:,:),at(:,:),am(:,:),am1(:,:)
CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: na
INTEGER :: m,n

na='B.txt'

a=loadm(na)
!CALL DISP('A =',a,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

m=size(a,1)
n=size(a,2)

ALLOCATE (at(n,m))
ALLOCATE (am(n,n))
ALLOCATE (af(n,n))

at=transpose(a)
am=matmul(at,a)
am1=am
!CALL DISP('ATA =',am1,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

af=cholesky(am)
CALL DISP('Ach ',af,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

af=transpose(af)
CALL DISP('AchT ',af,ADVANCE='DOUBLE')

ENDPROGRAM
```

UPDATE: Minimum compilable example. I took out the subroutine DISP() with its respective module. I also took out the module and function that made the comprobation of the symmetry of the matrix. Moreover, I took out the function that I wrote for reading the matrix from a file (I wrote the same matrix directly on the program) and the function for printing the matrix. The problem gets worse, now there are no numbers, not even the first row as before, all the matrix becomes NaN after the use of cholesky(). The gfortran version is 5.3.0

```
PROGRAM pcholstack
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: af(:,:),at(:,:),am(:,:),am1(:,:)
REAL :: a(3,4)
INTEGER :: m,n,i,j

a(1,1)=3
a(2,1)=2
a(3,1)=1
a(1,2)=2
a(2,2)=-3
a(3,2)=1
a(1,3)=4
a(2,3)=1
a(3,3)=2
a(1,4)=5
a(2,4)=-2
a(3,4)=1

m=size(a,1)
n=size(a,2)

do i=1,m,1
    write(*,1017),(a(i,j),j=1,n)
    end do
        1017 format (10f15.2)

write(*,*)

ALLOCATE (at(n,m))
ALLOCATE (am(n,n))
ALLOCATE (af(n,n))

at=transpose(a)
am=matmul(at,a)
am1=am
write(*,*) am1(1,1)
write(*,*)

do i=1,n,1
    write(*,1018),(at(i,j),j=1,m)
    end do
        1018 format (10f15.2)

write(*,*)

do i=1,n,1
    write(*,1019),(am(i,j),j=1,n)
    end do
        1019 format (10f15.2)

write(*,*)

af=cholesky(am)

!af=transpose(af)

do i=1,n,1
    write(*,1016),(af(i,j),j=1,n)
    end do
        1016 format (10f15.2) 

CONTAINS

FUNCTION cholesky(a)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: u(:,:),cholesky(:,:)
REAL :: a(:,:),s
INTEGER :: i,j,k,n

n=size(a,1)
ALLOCATE (u(n,n))
u=0.0
u(1,1)=sqrt(a(1,1))

DO j=2,n,1
    u(1,j)=a(1,j)/u(1,1)
END DO

DO i=2,n,1
    DO k=1,i-1,1
        s=s+(u(k,i)**2)
    END DO
    u(i,i)=sqrt(a(i,i)-s)
    s=0
    DO j=i+1,n,1
        DO k=1,i-1,1
            s=s+u(k,i)*u(k,j)
        END DO
        u(i,j)=(1/u(i,i))*(a(i,j)-s)
        s=0
    END DO
END DO

cholesky=u

ENDFUNCTION

ENDPROGRAM
```

Comment: Which spots? Please read [ask] and [mcve] we need an exact case and see the full input data and the full output from them.  We need to be able to replicate your computations.

Comment: Note that you are relying on Fortran 2003 automatic array allocation on assignment. This is not enabled by default in some compilers, notably older versions of Intel Fortran. How do you compile the sources?

Comment: You haven't shown the whole code so I can't be 100% sure, but from what I can see this code is illegal - cholesky has an assumed shape dummy argument but there is no interface in scope at the calling point. Please show a complete code so this can be checked. Also please use implicit none. Again because you don't show a whole program I can't tell for certain, but it appears that there is no declaration of cholesky in the program,

Comment: @VladimirF, I have already added the output computations. I am using gfortran as a compiler.

Comment: @IanBush What do "illegal code", "assumed shape" and "dummy argument" mean? I have used implicit none already. I have edited my post so now the module appears. Sorry, I forgot to state that "cholesky" is inside the declared module "funciones2".

Comment: You should compile with `-fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace` and run again. This should be done whenever you have a bug suspicion.

Comment: Your newest program does not produce any NaN on my computer.

Comment: @VladimirF Oh, I have changed it again because the debugger was sending an error regarding the declaration of u. Can you tell me if this new edit has any problem? Can we assume it is a bug in my compiler?

Comment: Not even after your change now. Still no NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Fortran identified that you are using `s` incorrectly in Cholesky. The value of `s` is not defined when you are first using it.

Thus, the result can be anything.

Probably you wanted to set it to 0.

```
> ifort cholesky.f90 -g -check -traceback -standard-semantics
> ./a.out 
           3.00           2.00           4.00           5.00
           2.00          -3.00           1.00          -2.00
           1.00           1.00           2.00           1.00

 14.00000

           3.00           2.00           1.00
           2.00          -3.00           1.00
           4.00           1.00           2.00
           5.00          -2.00           1.00

          14.00           1.00          16.00          12.00
           1.00          14.00           7.00          17.00
          16.00           7.00          21.00          20.00
          12.00          17.00          20.00          30.00

forrtl: severe (194): Run-Time Check Failure. The variable 'cholesky$S$_1' is being used in 'cholesky.f90(82,9)' without being defined
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000407DB7  pcholstack_IP_cho          82  cholesky.f90
a.out              0000000000405B47  MAIN__                     54  cholesky.f90
a.out              000000000040261E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00007F41B73496E5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402529  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

The reported code is:

```
s = 0  !you probably wanted

DO i=2,n,1
    DO k=1,i-1,1
        s=s+(u(k,i)**2)   !<<<=====
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in these two lines:

```
a=loadm(na)

a=matmul(transpose(a),a)
```

I do not have the code for `loadm`, but your `a` matrix is 4x3.  You then call `matmul` and put a 4x4 into it (and thus using memory not reserved for it, which other things can write to).  The `cholesky` function will see it as a 4x3, not a 4x4.

---

UPDATE:

It actually worked in `gfortran`, which automatically allocated the variables.   But it failed in `pgfortran`.

Here's the problem: The return value of `cholesky` is not properly defined.  The easiest thing to do is simply return `u`:

```
FUNCTION cholesky(a) result (u)
```

Take out the definition of the `cholesky` array, and do not assign to it at the end of the function.

Comment: I thought that could be the problem too, so I fixed like in the 2nd edit, assigning new variables to every new computed matrix, but the problem remains.

Comment: Now, `at` and `am` are not allocated.

Comment: I allocated them now, it is still failing

Comment: Found, and fixed, another problem.  Will add to answer momentarily.

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but the program "pchol" is still having the same problem. The function "cholesky" also works fine when I use as input data a square matrix. The problem occurs when I internally obtain a square matrix through the transposition and multiplication A^T*A.

Comment: So it's crashing on the `matmul` call?

Comment: Not exactly, I think there is a bug or something like that. When DISP('ATA =', am1, ADVANCE='DOUBLE') is turned on, everything works fine, cholesky makes the correct calculations and shows them. But when DISP(...) is turned off, the NaNs appear.

Comment: @MSalmer Out of curiosity, what do you get if you print the value of am1( 1, 1 ) instead of calling DISP() for am1? (before using cholesky?)

Comment: @MSalmer That screams memory overwrite.  Somewhere you are not properly allocating the arrays.  What compiler are you using?  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @roygvib Hey! When I printed the value of am1(1,1) as you said, without using DISP(), it actually worked! What is the problem, then?

Comment: @Jack I am using gfortran, but I haven't used debuggers yet. Which flag do you think I should use?

Comment: @MSalmer I think there are mainly two possiblities for the trouble.. One is that there is still some bug(s) in your code (which cannot be seen from the code in the question), and the other is that your gfortran version has some compiler bug(s), e.g., for a function with allocatable return array. (You can check the version by `gfortran -v`.) Anyway, I believe it would be very useful if you prepare a minimum compilable example (without using "dispmodule") so that we can try the code. Also, as suggested above,  attaching options like `-fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace` may give some hints.

Comment: You can use `gdb` as a debugger.  It is probably already installed.  For a graphical debugger, try `ddd`.  Other people may have other suggestions.  In all seriousness, when I taught programming, Lesson 1 was "Writing 'Hello, World'" and Lesson 2 was "Using the Debugger on 'Hello, World'".

Comment: I used the debugger "-Wall", which is sending me to tab-related problems, which I assume is not very serious. I have updated the program.  There are not NaN's with this new program. So maybe the problem is in one of the functions that I took out, like the symmetry comprobation or the reading-from-file (loadm()) function.